# Flutter : Create a User avatar with pop-up image

Tags: flutter, overlay, transition, popover, avatar

How to implement this design, I've tried containers and masking. I've tried clipping and containers but it's not working perfectly. The clipping is circular.

Comment: You need to learn how to ask a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), questions like this will often go unanswered because of ambiguity and lack of evidence, you may also be banned from asking similar questions in the future.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.